# Prevent item stretch in CSS grid column

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

I have the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    '. b b b b b b . p p p .'
    '. b b b b b b . s s s .';
  
  &__item {
    align-self: start;
    background-color: #999;
    
    &--body {
      grid-area: b;
      height: 20rem;
    }
    
    &--primarySidebar {
      grid-area: p;
    }
    
    &--secondarySidebar {
      grid-area: s;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--primarySidebar">
    Primary sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--secondarySidebar">
    Secondary sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

The output looks like this:

[image]

Codepen here: https://codepen.io/CaribouCode/pen/RwgRPvb

It looks like `primarySidebar` has stretched to fill 50% of the overall height. How do I prevent it doing that, and therefore remove the space between `primarySidebar` and `secondarySidebar`?

**Note:** It's essential I use grid and this DOM structure for other reasons, so what I'm looking for here is some CSS properties I can add to avoid the unwanted vertical space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to change the flow to `column` and specify the first two rows as `auto`, then tell the primary area to span 3 rows...like so.

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  width:100%;
  gap: 0.5em;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: #999;
}

.grid__item--body {
  grid-column: span 8;
  grid-row: span 3;
  height: 20rem;
}

.grid__item--primarySidebar {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.grid__item--secondarySidebar {
  grid-column: span 4;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--primarySidebar">
    Primary sidebar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi sint recusandae non ipsum vitae in vel labore quia corporis magni.
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--secondarySidebar">
    Secondary sidebar Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sequi sint recusandae non ipsum vitae in vel labore quia corporis magni
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks like it changes the design from a specific 12 column layout (which is required when I add media queries later) to an equal width 2 column layout.

Comment: @CaribouCode Answer update but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2px;
  /* define the number of grid columns */
  grid-template-columns: repeat( 12, minmax(250px, 1fr) );
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.grid__item {
  background-color: #999;
}

.grid__item--body {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: span 3;
  height: 20rem;
}

.grid__item--primarySidebar {
  grid-column: 2;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}

.grid__item--secondarySidebar {
  grid-column: 2;
  white-space: break-spaces;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--body">
    Body
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--primarySidebar">
    Primary sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="grid__item grid__item--secondarySidebar">
    Secondary sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This seems to remove my 12 column grid layout which I need when expanding this design

Comment: Please see the adjusted CSS. This link: "https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/" will be useful to make adjustments when expanding your design.

Answer (score -3):

I think it's not a grid problem - you added 20rem height in body, but didn't in sidebars - you can try to add 10rem each, or 100%

Comment: This is not a suggestions forum. Please provide answers you know to work.